# MongoDB follow an index from a collection via regex case insensitive

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I use various **indexed collections** in MongoDB where I make queries from a simple search engine.
The point of the matter is that I can't find a way to do these Regex queries in **case insensitive**, i.e. the queried collection doesn't follow the index.

this is the situation:(**This way the index is followed by the collection without problems**)

```
var query = req.query.name;

function(callback) {
  collection3.find({$or:[{ firstname: new RegExp('^'+query)},
  { email: new RegExp('^'+query)}]}).toArray(function(err, result3){ 
    if (err) return callback(err);
     locals.result3 = result3;
     callback();
  });
 },
 .........
 .........
```

I have tried in all possible ways but I cannot get the desired result, and I cannot find information specific to my problem, I have tried with:

```
collection3.find({$or:[{ firstname: new RegExp('^' +query+ '$', 'i')}, ......
collection3.find({$or:[{ firstname: new RegExp('^' +query,'i')}, ......
collection3.find({$or:[{ firstname: { $regex: query, $options: 'i' }},......
collection3.find({$or:[{ firstname: { $regex: new RegExp(`^${query}$`), $options: 'i'}},......
```

I also tried to bind it from the variable in various ways including:

```
var value = '^'+query;
var value = /^query/i;
```

`
In short, since there does not seem to be one
solution I would be grateful to anyone who helps me!

other ways of dealing with the problem would also be great
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var query = req.query.name;

function(callback) {
  collection3.find({
    $or:[
      {
        "firstname": {
          "$regex": `^${query}$`,
          "$options": "i"
        }
      },
      {
        "email": {
          "$regex": `^${query}$`,
          "$options": "i"
        }
      }
    ]
  }).toArray(function(err, result3){ 
    if (err) return callback(err);
    locals.result3 = result3;
    callback();
  });
}
```

Here is a working snippet: https://mongoplayground.net/p/mfmS7ugsWqr

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately it doesn't follow the index in this way either. :(

Comment: I updated my anwser. Can you try it again? It should work now.

Comment: Nothing to do, unfortunately fails to consider $ options: 'i',  "$regex": `^${query}$` seems to work but case sensitive,with $ options: 'i' doesn't want to follow the index. I don't know what to do other than recreate the indexes from scratch :(

Comment: Unbelievable, I was not expecting that there is no way to regex case insensitive following an index already created a collections  in mongodb! I hope someone can help me find the right way! thanks anyway

Comment: Wait... Here is the working snippet that I just created: https://mongoplayground.net/p/mfmS7ugsWqr . I will add it to the answer as well. Can you check it?

Comment: Thanks for the time, conceptually it would work as well, but the problem is that I find the result after many minutes, I repeat it seems like he doesn't care to follow the index. Differently without option: i in a few milliseconds finds everything but only in Case Sensitive !!! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you just need a case insensitive search, use a [collation](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/fundamentals/collations/#collations).  Create the indexes with the collation specifying case-insensitive:

```
collection3.createIndex({name: 1},{collation: {locale: "en", strength: 1, caseLevel: false}} ) 
collection3.createIndex({name: 1},{collation: {locale: "en", strength: 1, caseLevel: false}} )
```

And use the same collation when querying:

```
collection3.find({$or:[{name:query},{email:query}]}).collation({locale:"en",strength:1,caseLevel:false})
```

Comment: Ok thanks for sure I'll try to recreate the indexes! I wanted to know if there was a way to run the collection.find case insensitive with the indexes already created! since the data are so many, and it would take me a long time to recreate all the collections index from scratch

Comment: If queries will always be case-insensitive it would be best to assign the collation when creating the collection so that it is applied automatically, but that would mean reloading all of the data.

Comment: unfortunately in this way it fails to use regex! problem about a problem ... I'm about to give up on using mongodb! however strength must be set to 2 for case insensitive, thanks again!

Comment: When I submit the query as a regex, the explain plan says it is using the index. Also not sure why strength 1 didn't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

For those who find themselves in a similar problem, I temporarily solved (based on my need) by automatically setting the first letters of the name in uppercase before making the request in the req.query.name
(luckily the names all start in capital letters)

```
var query = req.query.name;
var value = '^'+query;
function toTitleCase(str) {
  return str.replace(
    /\w\S*/g,
    function(txt) {
      return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();
    }
  );
}

.............
.............
```

subsequently in place of **'^' + query** i added in new RegExp **toTitleCase(value)**

```
function(callback) {
  collection3.find({$or:[{ firstname: new RegExp(toTitleCase(value))},
  { email: new RegExp('^'+query)}]}).toArray(function(err, result3){ 
    if (err) return callback(err);
     locals.result3 = result3;
     callback();
  });
 },
 .........
 .........
```

in this way, even if I write in **lowercase** in the search bar, the request in **req.query.name** is made in **uppercase** only with the first letters of the beginning of each word.
leaving unchanged email, since they are obligatorily in lower case,
and the whole follows the index perfectly!

I was lucky because I have this syntax (the first letter always in uppercase) thus bypassing the problem, otherwise another idea was to bring the entire database back to lowercase at the root! It amazes me that to date there is no solution to this problem, at least as far as I am aware!

PS: If you have any other ideas, it would be welcome!
thanks